# Wt (Witty). Clueless about Javascript implentation not working

Tags: javascript, c++, wt

I'm stuck with the problem, where I'm trying to add event listener to popup menu through Javascript. But it looks, it's not attached or something. Because when I'm moving the cursor on the popup menu, the text widget value isn't changed. What I'm doing wrong?

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <vld.h>

#include <Wt/WApplication>
#include <Wt/WContainerWidget>
#include <Wt/WPushButton>
#include <Wt/WPopupMenu>
#include <Wt/WBreak>
#include <Wt/WJavaScript>

#include <windows.h>

class FooApplication : public Wt::WApplication {
public:
    FooApplication(Wt::WEnvironment const& env)
    : Wt::WApplication(env),
    container(new Wt::WContainerWidget(root())),
    signal(this, "signal"){

        text.setText("Press the button and You will see the current date and time.");
        text.setId("time");

        container.addWidget(&text);

        button.setId("button");
        button.setText("Date & Time!");
        button.setMenu(new Wt::WPopupMenu());
        //hider_button->menu()->setAutoHide(true, 0);
        button.menu()->setId("menu");
        button.menu()->addItem("First");
        button.menu()->addItem("Second");
        button.menu()->addItem("Third");
        button.menu()->addItem("Fourth");

        lineBreak = new Wt::WBreak(&container);

        container.addWidget(&button);

        button.clicked().connect([&](Wt::WMouseEvent const&) {
            text.doJavaScript("document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date()");
        });

        button.mouseWentOver().connect([&](Wt::WMouseEvent const&) {
            button.menu()->doJavaScript("document.getElementById('menu').style.overflow = 'hidden';");
            button.menu()->doJavaScript("document.getElementById('menu').style.height = '0px';");
            button.menu()->popup(&button);

            button.menu()->doJavaScript("function expand() {"
                "var target = document.getElementById('menu');"
                "var h = target.offsetHeight;"
                "var sh = target.scrollHeight;"
                "var loopTimer = setTimeout(expand, 8);"
                "if (h < sh) { h += 5; } else {"
                "clearTimeout(loopTimer); h = sh - 2;}"
                "target.style.height = h + \"px\";}"
                "expand();"
            );

            buttonMouseOn = true;
        });

        button.mouseWentOut().connect([&](Wt::WMouseEvent const&) {
            buttonMouseOn = false;
        });

        button.menu()->doJavaScript(
            "document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('onmouseenter', function(){"
            //+ signal.createCall() +
            "document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date()})"
        );

        signal.connect(this, &FooApplication::changeValue);

    }

    void changeValue() {
        Beep(523, 500);
        if (menuMouseOn){
            menuMouseOn = false;
        } else {
            menuMouseOn = true;
        }
    }

    static FooApplication* create(Wt::WEnvironment const& env) {
        return new FooApplication(env);
    }

private:
    Wt::WContainerWidget container;
    Wt::WBreak* lineBreak;
    Wt::WText text;
    Wt::WPushButton button;
    Wt::JSignal<void> signal;
    bool buttonMouseOn = false;
    bool menuMouseOn = false;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return Wt::WRun(argc, argv, &FooApplication::create);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `'mouseenter'`, not 'onmouseenter':

```
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { ... });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter

Comment: Changed that but it doesn't help.

Comment: `mouseenter` event was specific to IE and only latest versions of other browsers support it. See the link in my answer. As Wt is shipped with jQuery, you can use jQuery `.mouseenter()` event which simulates the original event. If you don't want to use jQuery, you can fall back to native `mouseover` event which is supported by all browsers.

Comment: Tried both, nothing happens. No errors, no nothing. Don't know If I'm using jQuery correctly, first time, just replaced the Javascript inside `button.menu()->doJavaScript()` with 
`"$(document).ready(function(){$('menu').mouseenter(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();});$('menu').mouseleave(function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();});});"`